# Xpath - Retrieve text from within a span with mailto href

Tags: html, xpath, hyperlink

I have this piece of HTML code. I've already tried several xpath selectors but don't seem to be able to get the "Ask us" text from within the span with class "someClass".

```
<span class="someClass"><a href="mailto:etcetc" target="_top">Ask us</a></span>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried already

Comment: Also, you definitely need to show a _complete, minimal_ HTML document, not just a very small snippet. Thanks. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the content from the link with "/text()"

For me works this XPath snippet on your example.

```
/span[@class="someClass"]/a/text()
```

Comment: or this: `//span[@class='someClass']/a[starts-with(@href,'mailTo')]/text()`

Answer (score 0):

```
string(//span[@class="someClass"])
```

> If you want the string() function to concatenate all child text, you
>   must then pass a single node instead of a node-set.